# How to get item details by its id from firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular6, dropdown

I have a dropdown of category  in my form and I am getting category  dropdown value from firebase database of category table, now once I submit the form then I am submit selected dropdown Id(category id) and other input field value,
(subcategory) to my firebase realtime database, which shown below in screenshot.

now I have to  display saved data in  list page so how can I get category name by reference saved id  in subcategory table, because only I have submitted catgoryid in subcategory table. 
hanks in Advance